# mysql fetch result parent id and category id by single query?

Tags: mysql

I have the table and values like this,

```
CREATE TABLE `category` (
`id` INT( 4 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
`category` VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL ,
`parent` INT( 4 ) NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO `category` VALUES (1, 'MCA', 9);
INSERT INTO `category` VALUES (2, 'M Tech', 9);
INSERT INTO `category` VALUES (3, 'B Tech', 9);
INSERT INTO `category` VALUES (4, 'BioTech', 9);
INSERT INTO `category` VALUES (5, 'InfoTech', 9);
INSERT INTO `category` VALUES (6, 'Chemical', 10);
INSERT INTO `category` VALUES (7, 'Indus', 10);
INSERT INTO `category` VALUES (8, 'Physics', 10);
INSERT INTO `category` VALUES (9, 'Information Science', 0);
INSERT INTO `category` VALUES (10, 'Others Science', 0);
```

I need a single query for getting the values in terms of category and subcategory.  3rd values zero as category and others are subcategory.

I need the output as tree structure like this,

Result is :

```
Information Science
    MCA
    M Tech
    B Tech
    BioTech
    InfoTech
Others Science
    Chemical
    Indus
    Physics
```

Comment: This is phrased a little awkwardly, perhaps an example of the output you need would be useful?

Answer (score 2):

Mysql has a **[nice article for you](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/)**.
Though personally I'd go for the Materialized Path

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you want:

```
SELECT
    T1.category AS category,
    T2.category AS subcategory
FROM category T1
JOIN category T2
ON T1.id = T2.parent
```

```
category               subcategory
'Information Science'  'MCA'
'Information Science'  'M Tech'
'Information Science'  'B Tech'
'Information Science'  'BioTech'
'Information Science'  'InfoTech'
'Others Science'       'Chemical'
'Others Science'       'Indus'
'Others Science'       'Physics'
```

This assumes that you only have two levels in your hierarchy.

Comment: May not return categories without subcategories